# Special dot character in string resource

Tags: android, kotlin

I was checking some sample string resources and I a found this dots that I can't seem to reproduce on my keyboard. All I can do is cut and paste them.

Does anyone know how I can create type these.

```
<string name="account_redacted">• • • • • • • • • • • • • </string>
```

Comment: "I can't seem to reproduce on my keyboard" -- the solution is likely to be OS-specific and is not really tied to programming. For example, based on the dot being elevated over the baseline, that could be "Syriac Supralinear Full Stop" (Unicode U+0701) (܁), and I'd use an Ubuntu "Characters" app to get one.

Comment: https://unicode.link/inspect/utf8:e2.80.a2

Comment: @CommonsWare since OP pasted the character in the question, it is instead a bullet point U+2022

Answer (score 1):

You can do with this shortcut **Option+8** if you use Mac and using British keyboard. Or you have to look your keyboard shortcuts settings according to your language.

Comment: I am actually using Linux (Fedora) so I don't have that option key

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the right character encoding to accomplish this effect. You could try with `&#8226;`

http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_index.html?q=bullet